# Android - How to test application with Expansion Files with Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, apk-expansion-files

I am developing an application for android devices which uses Expansion Files, and want to test it on AVD. My application contains code for manual download the Expansion Files, but it fails while running on AVD (calling `onDownloadStateChanged` method with value `STATE_FAILED_FETCHING_URL`, and shows the message: "Download stopped becouse he resources could not be found"). I tested the application on real devices and it worked. How can I make the download work, or add the Expansoin Files manually?

If it change sometiong, my computer runs Windows 7 and I use Eclipse IDE Juno Release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the expansion files onto your AVD through the command line or using the DDMS perspective in Eclipse.  In DDMS, select the File Explorer tab, then traverse to the directory the expansion files should be stored in.  Then select the cell phone with an incoming arrow icon.  You can then select the file to load onto the AVD.  Drawback to this method is it only allows uploading one file at a time.

You can use [adb commands to upload multiple files at once][1].

Comment: Thank you. How can I create the directory if it doesn't exists?

Comment: From DDMS perspective in Eclipse, the green + (plus) icon in the File Explorer tab is for adding folders.

Comment: Guys I have similar problem. In the DDMS file explorer I've put my folder into mnt/obb. And getZipExpansionFile() is returning NullPointerException. Now I'm thinking may be it shouldn't be in mnt/obb. Here is my question, if you'll answer I'll accept it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281178/getting-zip-expansion-file-causing-nullpointerexception-zip-is-not-placed-in-ri/22281565?noredirect=1#22281565 Thank you guys

Comment: @LeeNeverGup you could also use adb shell, ls, cd to the right folder, mkdir