# Getting zip expansion file causing NullPointerException. Zip is not placed in right directory of emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk-expansion-files

I'm trying to run the app in the eclipse emulator. In the ddms perspective, file explorer, I've put my .obb file inside mnt/obb/mypackage.name.example/main.1.mypackage.name.example.obb. Now Im getting NullPointerException at this line:

```
zip = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(ctx,1, -1);
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path needs to be

> Android/obb/com.example.android/

Its given [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing)

Just store the file in

> /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/

**EDIT**

This is a screenshot of an emulator running API Level 17

[image: Image showing /mnt/sdcard/Android folder on emulator running API level 17]

**EDIT 2**

In case you don't have an Android folder inside the sdcard, just create one

This folder hierarchy needs to exist

> /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/

**NOTE:** This will work only on devices/emulators having an sdcard. In case of a device without external storage, the path is different (since an emulated sdcard is maintained). Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453824/where-to-i-place-the-obb-file-to-test-android-expansion-pack-files-obb-on-my-n)

Comment: there is not Android folder in the mnt/sdcard in the file explorer in the DDMS perspective. should I just create it?

Comment: Could you tell me the API level of the emulator you are using?

Comment: my emulator is API level 9, 10'1 inch tablet

Comment: thanks AndyFaizan. Do you know where to put obb for the API level 9. cause my mnt/sdcard is empty.

Comment: I Checked. You're right about API level 9. No Android folder. I'm checking for a solution.

Comment: Why don't you try and make the /Android/obb hierarchy inside inside the mnt/sdcard/ folder?

Comment: if i try to create a folder "Android" in sdcard it says: "Failed. Read only file system"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49352/discussion-between-nazerke-and-andyfaizan)

Comment: Try remounting the file system.
First -> adb shell